# How to display Date and Time in Tamil Language?

Tags: date, multi-language, date-time

Am working in a Tamil blog site.There I want to display date in Tamil language.(ie)
 செவ்வாய்க்கிழமை, மே 23, 2017 .I need to display like this in wordpress site.But I dont want to change all.Only the date in tamil.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as describes it is far from trivial to display *just* the date in localized format.

The function for localized date output in WP is `date_i18n()`. But it doesn't have a concept of output in *arbitrary* locale. It always takes locale to use from global `$wp_locale` context.

You would have to pretty much rebuild this function from scratch, as well as loading of extra locale, to achieve this.

In a nutshell WP isn't really designed to work with multiple locales *within one page*. The low hanging solutions are either to go with it and switch locale completely or stick with numeric–only date formats.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the plugin "Real-Time Find and Replace" and replace the English months with tamil. For example, January to ஜனவரி etc.